What were the long-term environmental impacts of World War II on global ecosystems?
I want to know the long-term environmental consequences of World War II, including deforestation, habitat destruction, resource depletion, and nuclear fallout. Please throw some light on how wartime activities altered global ecosystems, affected biodiversity, and set the stage for modern environmental challenges. By examining these impacts, the question encourages a deeper understanding of the war's lasting legacy beyond political and social aspects.

I suspect the answer is several PhD's worth of research and analysis. It'll be interesting to see if anyone has been ambitious enough to try.

Here's your answer: https://osupress.oregonstate.edu/book/long-shadows If you want a deeper dive on the South Pacific specifically, then there's this one: https://uhpress.hawaii.edu/title/natives-and-exotics-world-war-ii-and-environment-in-the-southern-pacific/

Are you also including the impact of post-war reconstruction and industrialisation?

Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s).  Where have you looked so far? What research have you already done that we should not repeat. Are you quoting CEOBS? Is CEOBS relevant to your question?

A question like this has several issues on this site. First, the scope of your question is way to broad for a simple answer. A single item from your list might be addressable on a question and answer site, but your list would require a book length response to cover so many topics. Secondly, though the events you are looking at are in the past, Historians do not necessarily have the expertise to gage long-term environmental impacts, so it is debatable if such a question is on topic here in the first place.  Your question might do better on a discussion forum, not a Q&A site.

Please define "long term"; as in the long, long, term, the answer can only be nothing or everything. Either time and nature mitigate, or they are so overwhelmingly devastated that nothing is ever the same again. Since the latter didn't (and isn't seen to be) happening, we are on the path to the former. But History is about looking into the past rather than the future - so your question is grossly off topic here.

More specifically: all of Hiroshima, Nagasaki, Dresden, and Tokyo have recovered from WW2. Even Chernobyl and Fukushima have largely recovered from their accidents; and the WW1 Zones Rouges in France is now reduced to only about 40 sq. mi. after more than a century. Very little is forever - and when it is, it's never hidden.
